# How does mock-debugger control which line the debugger steps next?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I'm unable to understand how the [mock-debugger extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-mock-debug) controls where the next step is.

For example what if I'd like to step 2 lines if I find the word "banana" in my text? Also, I'd like to do something, like "Step In", where I can walk word-by-word - is it possible?

I've seen the `this._currentLine = ln;` assign, which looks like it controls where the line is, but it's just a simple local variable. How could it ever control anything in the debugger? I can't find any other uses of the `_currentLine` varbiable where it passes to anything useful API *(except for stack tracing, but I don't think it has any relation with the debugger line-control)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace is the only source for the debugger step visualization. When the debugger gets a notification to pause it requests the current stack trace. The TOS determines where the next execution point will be located. Hence the debug adapter is reponsible to determine this position precisely.

Comment: Sorry, for late reaction, and thank you very much, quite funny how I would never think that the debugger is actually driver by the stack trace :)